# how to tell the version number of dash?

Tags: linux, centos, dash-shell

I have a dash shell installed as `/bin/dash`.  I checked the manual of dash, which is the same as the POSIX shell manual, and there is nothing there to tell the version of the shell.

> dash --version

does not work.

How to tell the version number of dash I have??

Added:  some people are pointing me to Ubuntu commands, well, no I am not running Ubuntu, I am running Centos.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/283134/how-to-find-the-version-of-the-dash-shell-on-ubuntu-bin

Comment: Yes I know of this - I am not running Ubuntu

Comment: The accepted answer is CentOS-specific; also see [*How to find out the version number of `dash` without resorting to package management systems?* - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416760/how-to-find-out-the-version-number-of-dash-without-resorting-to-package-manage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems like Centos that use `rpm`:

```
rpm -q dash
```

Comment: not everyone has a package manager though

Comment: Echo the comment above. For example, how do you check the Dash version on macOS?

Comment: This question is tagged `linux` and `centos`, so it would be better to post a new question about macOS. Anyway, as far as I can tell, there is no way to identify the version of `/bin/dash` that ships with macOS. Its SCCS ident string is `@(#)PROGRAM:dash  PROJECT:dash-12`. There is no version 12 in [the dash git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git). I could not find the dash source code on [Apple's open source distribution site](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/).

Comment: I thought I could find this out with `man dash`, but no. It gives a date of January 19, 2003 even for relatively new dash-es in Debian bookworm.

Answer (score 3):

**dpkg -s**

> Run the following command:

```
dpkg -s dash
```

Comment: @tripleee thank you I was just fixated that it must be "inside" of dash itself, apparently not

Comment: not everyone has a package manager